# list of list of str

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a function that will open a .txt file in the shell as a list of list of str.

The file is something like:

```
TYUIO
GHJKL
BNMCV
ASDFG
XCVBN
```

And I need my function to return:

```
[['T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O'], ['G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L'], ...]
```

and so on.

The function I have written almost produces this. It returns:

```
[['TYUIO'], ['GHJKL'], ...]
```

and so on. What do I need to change/add to this function to make it return to correct nested list?

This is my function:

```
board_list = []
for line in board_file:
    items = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    items = [item.strip() for item in items]
    board_list.append(items)

return board_list
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `list()` and `extend()`.

```
items = [list(item.strip()) for item in items]
board_list.extend(items)
```

You can also do it in one line, assuming each line contains a single word. I'm not sure why you are splitting on `\t` so this might not work for you.

```
with open("data.txt") as board_file:
    board_list = [list(line) for line in board_file.read().split('\n') if line]
```

Comment: OP never breaks it down to a character level, the lowest he goes is to words.

Comment: But I thought: - `[item.strip() for item in items]` is doing that task. What's the difference when you add a `list` around the `item.strip()`, as we are already using `List Comprehension`.

Comment: `[ch for ch in 'rohit']` gives me correct result. I don't need a `list(ch)` there.

Comment: Because he `split()`s `items` it becomes a list. Each `item` in the comprehension is a word, not a character.

Comment: This almost gives me the right return data. when I change my function to:

board_list = []
    for line in board_file:
        items = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        items = [list(item.strip()) for item in items]
        board_list.append(items)

    return board_list

It has too many [] around each str. So it returns [[['T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O']], [['G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L']]]

Comment: @Tim.. Ah! Got it. Was missing that thing. +1

Comment: @user1816131: Ah, you should also be using `extend()` rather than `append()`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. changing the append() to extend() worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if the result of opening the text file was a list of lines , i will call this list as **listoflines** , so we can define this function :

```
def listof(listoflines):
    board_list = []
    board = []
    for element in listoflines:
       board_list.append((element.strip('\n')).split())
    for member in board_list:
       for i in range(len(member)):
          board.append(list(member[i]))

    return board
```

Comment: While this may technically answer the question your answer would be better if you explained _why_ it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you simply forget to convert string into list of values, to do this you can use [built-in map function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
items = map(list, items)
```